# How do I check if all odd numbers are greater than 10 in a list

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to write a function using recursion `eval :: Int -> Bool` that returns true if given a list where every odd number is greater than ten. For example:

```
eval [] == True
eval [1] == False
eval [2] == True
eval [1, 11, 21] == False
eval [2, 12, 22] == True
eval [21, 11] == True
```

I have to use recursion to do it, and I have got a base code:

```
eval :: [Int] -> Bool
eval [] = True
eval (x:xs) | mod x 2/= 0 && x > 10 = True
            | otherwise = eval xs
```

The code runs, but it does not work for lists with an odd number greater than 10 as the first input, as it takes the first value of the list as the standard. I think that sorting the list in ascending order first, then performing the recursion would work, is that correct and if so how do I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* return `True` if `mod x 2 /= 0 && x > 10`. At that point we still have to look for the rest of the numbers.

We thus can recurse on the tail only if the item is *even* or the item is greater than 10. Indeed, if an item is *even* then it is sufficient to continue, if it is not, we need to validate that that number is greater than 10.

So the `eval` function thus works with:

```
eval :: [Int] -> Bool
eval [] = True
eval (x:xs) | even x || x > 10 = eval xs
            | otherwise = False
```

We can simplify this with:

```
eval :: [Int] -> Bool
eval [] = True
eval (x:xs) = (even x || x > 10) && eval xs
```

We can also implement functions without the use of recursion, for example with a `foldr` pattern:

```
eval :: (Foldable f, Integral a) => f a -> Bool
eval = foldr (\x -> ((even x || x > 10) &&)) True
```

or work with [`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all):

```
eval :: (Foldable f, Integral a) => f a -> Bool
eval = all (\x -> even x || x > 10)
```

Comment: Oh, can you explain how the foldr pattern works? Like why isn't a list input required for eval?

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: because `foldr ... False` produces a function, and that function takes a list as argument.

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: the foldr pattern substitutes each `:` from the list in the function (here `\x -> (even x || x > 10) && xs`, and uses `True` for the empty list case `[]`.

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: see http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds

Comment: `all` is definitely clearest, but doesn't meet the requirement that the OP write their own recursion. `\x -> even x || x > 10` can be written `(||) <$> even <*> (>10)` or `liftA2 (||) even (>10)` if you're in that sort of mood.

Comment: @dfeuer: I agree that the `foldr` and `any` do not use explicit recursion, this was more to show how to use Haskell without having to define recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much just write down the problem specification:

```
f :: [Int] -> Bool
f = all (> 10) . filter odd
-- (And because you are supposed to write your own recursion)
  where all p (x : xs) = p x && all p xs
        all p [] = True
```